# What is Cast (part of Foundry)?

Tags: foundry, cast

I saw that Foundry has a CLI tool called Cast. What is it useful for?

Answer (score 1):

Cast is a tool part of [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry), the blazing fast, portable and modular toolkit for Ethereum application development.

To quote the README:

> Swiss army knife for interacting with EVM smart contracts, sending transactions and getting chain data.

Cast has lots of helpful utilities for Ethereum developers. For instance, there is a command for querying the ETH balance of an account:

```sh
cast balance 0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045
# prints 34011798284984006579
```

And there is a command for getting a wei value from a simple number:

```sh
cast --to-wei 15
# prints 15000000000000000000
```

Make